# Find the least positive integer $m$ such that $m^2 - m + 11$ is a product of at least four not necessarily distinct primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find the least positive integer $m$ such that $m^2 - m + 11$ is a product of at least four not necessarily distinct primes.

I tried but not able to solve it.

**Edit** : Please note that I am looking for mathematical solution not the programming one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By checking the choices $m=0,1,\ldots,p-1$, you can show that $m^2-m+11$ is never divisible by $p$ when $p=2,3,5$ or $7$. So the smallest possible product of four primes is $11^4$. The next smallest is $11^3\cdot 13$. (Taking a peek at Kenny Lau's answer). All you need to do is to check that
$$m^2-m+11=11^4$$
has no integer solutions, but
$$m^2-m+11=11^3\cdot13$$
does.

Comment: Because the question was about the least positive $m$ I guess you also need to prove that $m^2-m+11$ is an increasing function of $m$ in the range $[1,\infty)$. Leaving that as an exercise.

Comment: How do you know *a priori* that no $m^2-m+11$ is divisible by $2,3,5,7$?

Comment: @Raffaele: See my comment under the main question. That fact is also easy to verify by the method outlined in my answer. And you also observe it first hand if you factor as many values of $m^2-m+11$ as you can muster. That would be a fitting piece of preliminary work when battling a contest problem. Rarer in homework, which is why I had less qualms about answering this.

Comment: $n^2-n+11$ is one of those famous "prime producing polynomials". The most famous example of that lot is $p(n)=n^2+n+41$ which has the property that $p(k)$ is a prime for **all** $k, 0\le k<40$. These are all related to [Heegner numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number). I'm sure this is underlying the design of this problem. I chose not to use it in the actual answer, but voters apparently disagree :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let the equality $$m(m-1)+11=N$$ It is clear that $N$ must be odd and that can be divisible by the prime $11$. However the following congruences have no solution as it is easy to prove directly checking the few possibilities with $m(m-1)$ not divisible by $3,5$ and $7$ respectively

$$\begin{cases}m(m-1)+2\equiv 0\pmod3\\m(m-1)+1\equiv 0\pmod5\\m(m-1)+4\equiv 0\pmod7\end{cases}$$

Thus $N=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ with $p_i\ge11$.

A necessary condition is that (solving the quadratic in $m$) $$\sqrt{4N-43}=x^2$$ and from this we need that $$N\equiv 1,3,7\pmod{10}$$ By chance we find the minimum $N=11^3\cdot13$ which corresponds to $\color{red}{m=132}$ and that could have been calculated by direct trials but the next solution seems to be far from $132$.

Answer (score -1):

$$132^2 - 132 + 11 = 11 \times 11 \times 11 \times 13$$

[Pyth program](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%3C3lP%2B%2aTtT11&debug=0):

```
f<3lP+*TtT11
```

Comment: @new_born if you had some approach already started, and wrote about that in your question, we could've worked on that. As it stands, this is a full answer to your question. Also, brute force is a completely accepted proof method.